# Trying to preg_replace URL

Tags: php, preg-replace

I see a lot of Q&A in here about this, but none seem to be exactly what I need. I have large text field that could contain multiple URLs in it. The original URLs could be absolute or relative. I decided to make the absolute ones relative as a start and that works. But, I cannot for the life of me figure out how to match a pattern of "/anything-in-here/p/" to replace. Here is my example:

```
$original = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="http://example.com/url-written-text/p/12345">consectetur</a> adipiscing elit. Morbi iaculis nisl et enim <a href="
/more-url-text/p/54321">fermentum imperdiet.';

$newText = preg_replace('/http:\/\/example.com/', '', $original);

$newText = preg_replace('/\/[^*\/p\/]/', 'page?=', $newText);
```

I need the URLs to be "/page?=12345" replaced in the text field. Can anyone help or direct me to another question? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out

```
$newText = preg_replace('/href=\"(\S+)\/p\//', 'href="/page?=', $original);
```

It searches for strings like: 'href=".../p/', where ... contains any character which is not a white space.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it. I had gone cross-eyed with all of the different switches, classes, etcs.